# Flags.log.split is not a Function - Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, frontend

I'm having this error on a web project using Polymer. The exact line is the following.

```
var parts = flags.log.split(","); -> Is not a function
```

I have read in some forums that the problem is caused by the order of the scripts imported, and that webcomponents.js must be the first script imported, but I'm still having the same error.

Comment: i m having same erro in meteor.js,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error. It was a custom element I downloaded from github who was throwing the error.

Comment: was it app-router.html?

Answer (score 3):

Not only **Scripts** order but also make sure the script is loaded before the **HTML imports**.

```
<!-- Scripts Imports -->    
<script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>

<!-- HTML Imports -->
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-elements/paper-elements.html">
```

I found out the best place to put these are before any other links or scripts in the **HEAD**.

Comment: I`m still having the same problem. The first import in my code is webcomponents.js, anyway, it looks like polymer injects some meta and some style tags, as you can see in the code.   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzusW7ssGuDSX0dUN0YtbmpkVE0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I am not able to test your specific scenario but try turning off phantomjs and any other functionality that adds elements above the webcomponents import.